# Accessing local repository in offline mode

Tags: maven, maven-3

I need to make Maven access local repository (file://) when it is ran in offline mode (basically, I am trying to setup repository hierarchy so it does not put artifacts where I don't need them).

This does not work out-of-the-box, though I always assumed this scenario is supported. Is there some flag to enable particular repository in offline mode?

Answer (score 20):

For the dev environment only, if you use IntelliJ IDEA, you can configure Maven to work offline as follow:

```
Preferences... > Search for Maven > Work offline (checked)
```

Comment: My issue was the other way around, it used offline configuration to fix dependencies while not being able to fetch any maven repo. Unchecking then checking it again fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [set up profiles for repositories utilizing the local file system](http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/04/running-maven-offline-using-local.html) rather than a network address.

```
<repository>
   <id>mymaven</id>
   <url>file://D:\mylocalrepo</url>
</repository>
```

According to documentation, it is also possible to [reference offline mode in a property value](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Properties).

```
${settings.offline}
```

You would then leverage these together to [activate a given settings profile](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Activation) according to the examples [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). (If Maven doesn't detect the property, try evaluating it directly using the above syntax.)

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>myNeededProfile</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        ...
        <property>
          <name>offline</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
        ...
      </activation>
      ...
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

I believe that the [Maven Help Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) can guide this development by computing which profile will be active under certain conditions.

I also think that this could be accomplished more simply by explicitly invoking a profile from the command line each time offline mode is requested.

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -o -P profile-1,profile-2
```

Or, even more straightforwardly, by having two separate settings files and subbing them out specifically for the offline/online operations. You could write a command-line wrapper in whatever OS environment you're using to detect the offline request, then move and rename the files before executing the Maven commands, then move them back upon completion.

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I need a way to run Maven in offline mode (I need it to force Tycho plugin prefer local P2 repos) and still have hierarchy of repos (so some repos are r/o)

Answer (score 1):

Maven always tried to connect to central repository. You can define own central (it is only property, which you can redefine)

```
<repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>My Central</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>${my_url}</url>
    </repository>
```

Make the same for snapshot, plugin repository etc. Configuration you can use as profile - it will be optional. See [ingyhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325452/ingyhere) answer.

Comment: My problem is that when Maven is offline then the Tycho will ignore my local P2 repositories and will start fetching artifacts from the web. Hence I can't use online mode even if I override the central.

Comment: Have you tried redefining repository references from the parent project POM AND in the Maven master settings? Also, please reference more detail in the original question. This is a project issue where the Maven settings are overridden for some reason, or the project design does not accommodate offline mode. A specific solution rather than a general one needs to be approached.