# Why won't my multi-module Maven project install some of the modules?

Tags: maven

I'm using Maven for a project where one child project depends on another child project. When I do a `mvn clean install`, it builds them in the correct order (first the dependency, then the project that needs it), but in the project with the dependency, it downloads it from a remote repo instead of using the one I just built.

Looking at my logs, I see that it's not installing the dependency, even though I'm using the `install` target. EDIT: It does install some of the dependencies, just not the one I want.

How do I fix this?

Comment: See [Accessing local repository in offline mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576345/accessing-local-repository-in-offline-mode/9579997#9579997)

Comment: @ajozwik That might help, but I'm mainly just confused about why it's pulling from the remote repo at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Maven installs modules in the order that they're defined in the superpom.

Mine was like this:

```
<modules>
    <!-- module-a depends on module-b -->
    <module>module-a</module>
    <module>module-b</module>
</modules>
```

Giving us this build order:

1. Build `module-b` (as a dependency)
2. Build `module-a`
3. Install `module-a`
4. Install `module-b`

Since `module-b` isn't installed at step 2, it downloads `module-b` from the remote repo, and then the build fails since it's the wrong version.